# How to listen to EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged event?

Tags: c#, events, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have component which is wrapped around `EditForm` with the model set. `EditForm` contains in turn some components based on `InputBase`.

On change `InbutBase` triggers event EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged but I fail to spot connection between this event and `EditForm`. I already tried to listen to "onChange" on `EditForm` -- nothing.

So how to listen to this event?

*I would like to listen to single event from entire form rather than listening to multiple events coming from multiple inputs within form.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way -- I made the class managing the model `IDisposable` and added constructor:

```
public Markers()
{
  this.editContext = new EditContext(this);
  this.editContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContextOnOnFieldChanged;
}

public void Dispose()
{
  this.editContext.OnFieldChanged -= EditContextOnOnFieldChanged;
}

private void EditContextOnOnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

then instead of setting `Model` for `EditForm` I set `EditContext` which I just created.

A bit twisted because I thought it will be possible to do solely within markup but I will live :-).